# gitlab-ci Auto Devops: mvn: command not found on test step

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried to enable an "Auto Devops" pipeline for my private project on Gitlab.com. The "Build" step runs fine, but then the "Test" step fails. What's strange is that the beginning of the step goes well (the `mvn test-compile` part), but then it seems to lose the path to `mvn`:

```
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ setup_test_db
$ cp -R . /tmp/app
$ /bin/herokuish buildpack test
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
-----> Executing: mvn clean dependency:resolve-plugins test-compile
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...

<SNIP>

       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 9.953 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-01T17:22:11+00:00
       [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/169M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/tmp/buildpacks/05_buildpack-java/bin/test: line 24: mvn: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in heroku java buildpack < v60 that will mess with maven installation during tests execution.

It has been [fixed](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/pull/94) and bundled in herokuish 0.4.1

If you re-run your autodevops now it will work.

source: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44980

Comment: Awesome, I was suspecting something like this but did not take the time to do a proper PR. Thanks a lot!